# C# Limiting and classifying Text-Box input according to Check-Boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, radio-button

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B07nQ.png) i have three Check-Boxes and a text-box and i want to teach my application some characters therefore i need to classify the character input in text-box into three classes. The text-box should contain only one character (solved), and after the character input i classify it by checking one of three check-boxes. If digit entered i check "DIGIT" check-box, if letter entered (lower/upper case) i check "UPPERCASE" check-box, and if symbol, i check "AllSymbols" check-box.
If i enter Digit and check the UPPERCASE or AllSymbols instead of "DIGIT" check-box, it should throw an error notification(solved) after pressing OK. I need the same logic for the two other classes.

```
public void GetParameters(out string charCode, out int classes)
{
    charCode = textBoxCharCode.Text;

    try
    {
        if (checkBoxDigit.Checked) Convert.ToInt16(textBoxCharCode.Text);
    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You should enter Digits", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }

    if (charCode.Length != 1) MessageBox.Show("You should enter only One character", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

    classes = (checkBoxDigit.Checked ? (int)EOCRClass.Digit : 0) | (checkBoxUpperCase.Checked ? (int)EOCRClass.UpperCase : 0) | (checkBoxAllSymbols.Checked ? (int)EOCRClass.LowerCase : 0);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the only problem "how to check whether a string contains only upper case or lower case characters?" Or do you need something around textbox validation as well?

Comment: I edited my question,please check it. I need to check if text-box has a letter or a symbol, and classify them accordingly, else , throw and error after pressing OK button.

Comment: Unfortunately i still don't understand you completely.. on the [`Char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) class there are methods in the .NET Framework that can identify a Character, UpperCase character and so on, hope that helps you..

Comment: My english is a bit terrible, but Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 3 regex. One for numeric(digit) (class 0) , one for uppercase (class 1) and one for all symbols(class 2).
At the Ok button click event , check the checkbox checked (class 0 or 1 or 2 ) and validate the input in the textbox against the appropriate regex.
If the validation fails ,throw the error notification.